# Would there be any value in creating a tool to simplify code navigation?

Tags: software-industry, software-development, developer, tech-industry, software

A friend and I noticed that it's difficult to grasp new sets of code. In school, we're taught concepts in the form of visual representations - graphs. Would there be any value in creating something that allows for navigating code through graphs and inter-dependency webs, rather than through raw code? I've found a few open-source code navigation tools and was wondering why they aren't widely-used. My hypothesis is that understanding new code sets becomes simpler through experience and that a navigation tool might add an additional, unnecessary layer of complexity.

Comment: Why stop at navigating? The Unreal game engine for instance has one mode where it allows you to drag and drop different components to build an actual game. If you're going to have a visual graph-like structure, at least allow us to do some work with it. I personally would dislike having to exit my coding environment and change modes just to look at a representation of my code. But if you're looking to help beginners, you could always give it a try I suppose.

Comment: Do you mean something like the UML class diagrams built into JetBrains IDEA? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/class-diagram.html#analyze_class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your hypothesis is worthless. You need to actually interview people to find out.

I suggest you make a demo of what your graph would look like, and go to university coding departments and ask people what they think. Tell them it's for your masters thesis.

You'll likely find some people find it very useful, and others do not. Some people are visual learners, some are not. Most likely, Experienced developers would not find it so useful, as they are not visual learners, as the medium to learn visually doesn't exist. So you would target coding schools.